# ORA-00907 Missing Right Parenthesis in View Script after adding cols

Tags: sql, oracle

This view script is missing a right parenthesis and I cant figure out where it is. I'd appreciate any help
I've tried debugging for hours and can't figure it out. I've even tried online sql checkers I'd appreciate any help or suggestions thank you for your time. Is there an online website that can determine the syntax error faster? :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_VIEW_SCRIPT AS
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 
        EFFECTIVE_DT,
        SOURCE_CD,
        VIEW_CD,
        SDEX_TRAN_CODE TRANSACTION_CD,
        'missing' TRANSACTION_DESC,
        'missing' TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_TXT,
        'Y' TRANSACTION_CODE_ACTIVE_IND,
        Trunc(SYSDATE) TRANSACTION_CODE_START_DT,
        NULL TRANSACTION_REVERSAL_CD,
        NULL PRINCIPLE_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL INCOME_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL SHARES_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL COST_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        'INVEST1' ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_CD
    FROM TRD_FPCMS_TRANS_FULL_01_STG
    WHERE SDEX_TRAN_CODE IS NOT NULL
    AND SOURCE_CD != 'INSTIO'
    UNION
    SELECT 
        EFFECTIVE_DT,
        SOURCE_CD,
        VIEW_CD,
        SDEX_TRAN_CODE TRANSACTION_CD,
        'missing' TRANSACTION_DESC,
        'missing' TRANSACTION_CATEGORY_TXT,
        'Y' TRANSACTION_CODE_ACTIVE_IND,
        Trunc(SYSDATE) TRANSACTION_CODE_START_DT,
        NULL TRANSACTION_REVERSAL_CD,
        NULL PRINCIPLE_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL INCOME_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL SHARES_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        NULL COST_MULTIPLICATION_NBR,
        'INVEST1' ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_CD
    FROM TRD_FPCMS_TRANS_FULL_01_STG
    WHERE SDEX_TRAN_CODE IS NOT NULL
) stg
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM accounting_transaction_code tgt
    WHERE tgt.TRANSACTION_CD = stg.TRANSACTION_CD)
UNION
SELECT 
    businessdt effective_dt,
    holding_source_cd source_cd,
    holding_view_cd view_cd,
    txn.transaction_cd,
    txn.tran_desc transaction_desc,
    'missing' transaction_category_txt,
    'Y' transaction_code_active_ind,
    TRUNC(sysdate) transaction_code_start_dt,
    NULL transaction_reversal_cd,
    NULL principle_multiplication_nbr,
    NULL income_multiplication_nbr,
    NULL shares_multiplication_nbr,
    NULL cost_multiplication_nbr,
    'GENEVA' ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM_CD
FROM transactions_gva_kfk_stg tks, (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN LEAD(transaction_cd) OVER (ORDER BY transaction_cd) = transaction_cd
            THEN  substr(transaction_cd,1,6)||substr(sys_guid(),6,6)
            ELSE transaction_cd  END transaction_cd,
            tran_desc
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            CASE WHEN (
                SELECT COUNT(1) 
                FROM accounting_transaction_code 
                WHERE transaction_cd =  UPPER(substr(trxcd,1,12))
            ) = 0
            THEN  UPPER(substr(trxcd,1,12))
            WHEN (
                SELECT COUNT(1) 
                FROM accounting_transaction_code 
                WHERE transaction_cd =  UPPER(substr(trxcd,1,6)||substr(trxcd,-6))
            ) = 0
            THEN  UPPER(substr(trxcd,1,6)||substr(trxcd,-6))
            ELSE substr(trxcd,1,6)||substr(sys_guid(),6,6)
            END transaction_cd,  tran_desc
        FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT 
                gva.trxcd tran_desc, 
                regexp_replace(UPPER(trxcd),'[^A-Z0-9]') trxcd
                FROM transactions_gva_kfk_stg gva
                             WHERE NOT EXISTS
                             (SELECT 1
                             FROM accounting_transaction_code tgt
                             WHERE tgt.transaction_desc = gva.trxcd)
                             ) ORDER BY transaction_cd)) txn
 WHERE txn.tran_desc = tks.trxcd
   AND  NOT EXISTS
     (SELECT 1
     FROM accounting_transaction_code tgt
     WHERE tgt.transaction_desc = tks.trxcd);
```

Comment: Notice after txn (the correlation name of the derived table), you're missing an ON clause corresponding to the JOIN keyword.  The ON clause is required in standard SQL and many databases, including oracle.  If you used a CROSS JOIN, the WHERE clause is good enough (in the case of an inner join).  Oracle likely requires the ON clause as well, if you keep the JOIN keyword as is.  A little more attention to formatting might help spot that kind of error.  Missing keyword is because we find the WHERE keyword when we're expecting the ON keyword.

Comment: It's best to break down the statement into the smallest testable components.  Otherwise, it can be difficult to spot small mistakes like this.  Simplify each basic operation to make sure the form is correct.  There's no need to have the subqueries to notice the missing ON keyword.

Comment: As an example, here's the testing I performed before I noticed the JOIN / ON issue, near the end of the test cases, plus the final query which tests the JOIN syntax without an ON clause in a very trivial example: https://dbfiddle.uk/_a0JA1vQ   ... If you might like this in the form of an answer, let me know.  Otherwise, I consider this just a simple syntax error, usually not requiring a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to have added those 2 columns to only one of the SELECT statements, you need to add them to all the SELECT statements that are being UNIONed together. When you union select statements, each statement needs to return the same number of columns, with the same datatypes, in the same order

Comment: I am still having trouble and edited my original post to account for these updates. I'd appreciate if you could check it out.

Comment: What’s the full error message - presumably it gives some indication where in your SQL it thinks there’s an issue? Also, where you have comments, I believe you need a space after the 2 hyphens and before the actual comment text

Comment: The full error message is ORA-00905 missing keyword